# How to create a dynamic root in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have admins and normal users in my webapp.  I want to make their root (/) different depending on who they are.  The root is accessed from many different pages, so it would be much easier if I could make this happen in the routes.rb file.  Here is my current file.

```
ProjectManager::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "projects#index"
end
```

Can someone please link me to an example that can show me the direction to go in?  Is there any way to put logic into the routes file?  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 7):

You can just create controller for root route.

```
class RoutesController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def root
    root_p = case current_user.role
      when 'admin'
        SOME_ADMIN_PATH
      when 'manager'
        SOME_MANAGER_PATH
      else
        SOME_DEFAULT_PATH
      end

    redirect_to root_p
  end
end
```

In your routes.rb:

```
  root 'routes#root'
```

P.S. example expects using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), but you can customize it for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different options:

**1. lambda in the routes file(not very railsy)**

[previously explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963819/1536309)

**2. redirection in application controller based on a before filter(this is optimal but your admin route will not be at the root)**

source [rails guides - routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root)

you would have two routes, and two controllers. for example you might have a `HomeController` and then an `AdminController`.  Each of those would have an `index` action.

your `config/routes.rb` file would have

```
namespace :admin do
  root to: "admin#index"
end

root to: "home#index"
```

The namespace method gives you a route at `/admin` and the regular root would be accessible at `'/'`

Then to be safe; in your admin controller add a before_filter to redirect any non admins, and in your home controller you could redirect any admin users.

**3. dynamically changing the layout based on user role.**

In the same controller that your root is going to, add a helper method that changes the layout.

```
layout :admin_layout_filter
private
def admin_layout_filter
  if admin_user?
    "admin"
  else
    "application"
  end
end

def admin_user?
  current_user.present? && current_user.admin?
end
```

Then in your layouts folder, add a file called `admin.html.erb`

source: [rails guides - layouts and routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-layout-option)

Answer (score 0):

You can't truly change the root dynamically, but there's a couple of ways you can fake it.

The solution you want needs to take place in either your application controller or the "default" root controller. The cleanest/easiest solution is simply to have your application controller redirect to the appropriate action in a before filter that only runs for that page. This will cause the users' url to change, however, and they won't really be at the root anymore.

Your second option is to have the method you've specified as root render a different view under whatever conditions you're looking for. If this requires any major changes in logic beyond simply loading a separate view, however, you're better off redirecting.