# Rails root path based on user intput

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I need to let the user select a root path (or a get) to be one of many pages he has created. That means, i want to be able to created the page "fantastic page" and set it to be the front page (http://example.com/).

Is this at all possible? I have tried sending the user to a fixed action and redirecting the user to the selected action but that leaves me with a route like this: http://example.com/page/8

My desired result is: http://example.com/
(while the page is the one selected by the user).

Any help is appreciated :)

**Edit:** I need to clarify. I want the user to be able to select a page or a photo. That means I need the user to be able so select both the controller and the action.

Something like this:

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
    get "/" => '#{user_selected_controller}#{user_selected_action}/#{:id}'
end
```

The code above is completely wrong. But i think it illustrates what i want to accomplish.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a dynamic root in Rails 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960977/how-to-create-a-dynamic-root-in-rails-3)

Comment: This sounds more like a problem for a helper method that picks the correct route than a dynamic route.

Comment: How would a helper method like that look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem not through routing but by creating a polymorphic association to both Pages and Galleries with the users table. Like this:

First create polymorphic association

```
# In my page model
has_one :user, :as => :home

# In my Gallery model
has_one :user, :as => :home

# In my User model
belongs_to :home, polymorphic: true
```

Then i used this as my controller in the users_controller:

```
def home
    # Multitenant rails app. This refers to user who owns the subdomain visited.
    @user = current_tenant

    # This is not optimal, results in two queries.
    if @user.home_type.classify.constantize.exists?(@user.home_id)

        # This is the same as @page = Page.find(params[:id])
        instance_variable_set("@#{@user.home_type.downcase}", @user.home_type.classify.constantize.find(@user.home_id))

        # this is the same as render 'pages/show', layout: false
        render "#{@user.home_type.downcase.pluralize}/show", layout: false
    else
        redirect_to photos_path
    end

end
```

My routes look like this:

```
# Set a page as the home screen
post 'pages/set_home/:id' => 'pages#set_home', as: :set_home_page

# User selected Home screen
get "/" => 'users#home'
```

Setting a home page:

```
# In pages_controller
  def set_home
    @user = current_user
    @user.home = @page
    if @user.save
      redirect_to pages_path, notice: "Home screen set to #{@page.title}"
    else
      redirect_to pages_path, alert: "An error occured. Home not set."
    end
  end
```

This way i could load the relevant resource through the users.home variable, while using a normal route to the users controller home action.

This might be an inefficiently solution, but its the only one i could think of. Please feel free to suggest improvements :)

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly render the page view from the controller.

config/routes.rb

```
root to: 'home#index'
```

controllers/home_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @page = #get fantastic page
  render 'pages/page', page: @page
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller.